# Two Point Hospital crashes during loading screen and crashes Steam as well

Tags: technical-issues, linux, two-point-hospital

I installed the game yesterday. When I decided to launch the game all went well until it arrived at the loading screen. After it showed the Sega logo, it stayed there for 20 seconds, and after that it crashed and also crashed Steam.
I have tried the game on Windows with the same system, and it works fine. It seems to be a problem with Linux, as I am currently running Ubuntu.
(I am using proton 7)

Answer (score 1):

Two Point Hospital needs at least [Proton 7.0-1](https://www.protondb.com/app/535930) as of writing to work. You can set the Proton version in the Steam compatibility settings page

Comment: Already tried that

Comment: Can you update your post with the Proton version you're using?

Comment: I wase proton 7 but now when i open it says falied to initialize engine graphics failed